# For real scalars $a,b$ and a nonzero vector $v$ in a vector space, prove that if $av=bv$ then $a=b$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

Is it possible to prove this using the axioms of a vector space? I tried playing around with the $a(v+w)=av+aw$ and $(a+b)v=av+bv$ axioms, but to no avail because I always got back to where I started. i.e. if I replaced the $bv$ with $av$ in the second axiom, I get $(a+b)v=av+av$ then $av+bv=av=av$ and then $av=bv$.

Comment: If $av = bv$ then $av - bv = 0$, so $(a-b)v = 0$. Can you conclude anything from this?

Comment: Then (a-b) must be equal to 0 because v is nonzero and if a-b=0 then a=b, okay that makes sense, thanks

Comment: NateRob Please include in your post what you wrote while "playing around with" the equations?   I see no indication in your post of what you tried, nor what you consider to be of "no avail."  This site is not a "do-my-homework-for-me site."  You can find many such sites, but you have to pay for them.

Comment: Should say:  I don't think this is entirely trivial. You must argue that $a\vec v=\vec 0$ implies $a=0$ (given that $\vec v \neq \vec 0$).  That does follow from the axioms but it needs an argument.

Comment: @amWhy Okay I added what I tried to do

Comment: @lulu Maybe you could say that ax=0 implies that either a=0 or x=0 which you could prove by assuming that a=0 is false thus x=0 has to be true (you can divide both sides by a maybe because you know it's not 0). Then you could use that knowledge for the proof to this question -- because x is nonzero, (a-b) has to be zero.

Comment: Good!  That's exactly right.  If $a\neq 0$ then $a\vec v=0\implies a^{-1}a\vec v = a^{-1}\vec 0\implies \vec v = 0$ and you are done.  Here, of course, we are relying on the axiom which tells us that $1\times \vec v=\vec v$ for all $\vec v$,.

Comment: Thanks, @NateRob!

Answer (score 1):

I use a single axiom to define vector space:

> A vector space is an abelian group $V$ together with an action by a field $F$.

Then from $0v+0v=(0+0)v=0v$, we conclude $0v=0$ for all $v\in V$.
Likewise, $a0=a(0+0)=a0+a0$ implies $a0=0$ for all $a\in F$.

Now if $av=bv$ and $a\ne b$, we thus have
$$ v=1v=(a-b)^{-1}(a-b)v=(a-b)^{-1}(av-bv)=(a-b)^{-1}0=0.$$